# How to set custom DNS servers and use DHCP on kubuntu 20.04 using netplan config?

Tags: networking, kubuntu, 20.04, dns, netplan

Ok it is confusing so here is a clear version of what is going on. I am only able to set custom DNS servers using the /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml if i use the configuration below with a static IP address:

```
d@a:~$ more /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [10.0.0.49/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1   
      access-points:
        accesspointename:
          password: passwordgoeshere
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8,1.1.0.0,1.1.1.1]
```

The configuration above works, Network Manager restarts after issuing
`sudo netplan --debug apply`, there is a new connection that is created with the same name as my original access point but prepended with netplan-wlp3s0.

I would like not to use a static IP address. When i try the below configuration to set custom DNS servers and have DHCP enabled. No new connection is created and the original one has the service providers DNS servers.

```
d@a:~$ more /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: no
      access-points:
        accesspointname:
          password: passwordgoeshere
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8,1.1.0.0,1.1.1.1]

d@a:~$ sudo netplan --debug apply
** (generate:11280): DEBUG: 22:03:24.251: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml..
** (generate:11280): DEBUG: 22:03:24.251: starting new processing pass
** (generate:11280): DEBUG: 22:03:24.251: wlp3s0: adding wifi AP 'accesspointname'
** (generate:11280): DEBUG: 22:03:24.252: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:11280): DEBUG: 22:03:24.252: wlp3s0: setting default backend to 2
** (generate:11280): DEBUG: 22:03:24.252: Configuration is valid
** (generate:11280): DEBUG: 22:03:24.252: Generating output files..
** (generate:11280): DEBUG: 22:03:24.252: networkd: definition wlp3s0 is not for us (backend 2)
(generate:11280): GLib-DEBUG: 22:03:24.252: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
DEBUG:no netplan generated networkd configuration exists
DEBUG:netplan generated NM configuration changed, restarting NM
DEBUG:wlp3s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets: {}
  vlans: {}
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      access-points:
        accesspointname:
          password: passwordgoeshere
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.4.4
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 1.1.0.0
        - 1.1.1.1

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: enp0s25
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp0s25
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for wlp3s0
```

How can i keep DHCP on and use custom DNS servers?

Thanks

Comment: Your report is very confusing, because you show source yaml that specifies the networkd backend but then you show output that indicates the config is being applied in NetworkManager, so the yaml you're showing must be incomplete? Also neither the source yaml nor the debug output shows that you have specified a source for address assignment: both DHCP and static are off by default.  If NetworkManager is using DHCP despite this not being specified in the config, that's a netplan bug.

Comment: That said, if it IS your intent to use DHCP (as seems to be the case), then you want `dhcp4-overrides: use-dns: no` since DHCP-provided DNS takes precedence over statically configured DNS.

Comment: Ah now I see in the debug output that /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml exists, so this is a desktop which has config forcing all devices to use the NetworkManager backend.  In that case it's confusing / misleading to have `renderer: networkd` declared in the other yaml file.

Comment: thanks for your response, i updated the question with exact details of what is happening